# C structure member is a string, how to assign bytes directly

Tags: c, string, struct

I am working on a simple filesystem, which (obviously) contains folders, files, etc.

A (simplified version of a) folder is represented by a structure while in RAM like so:

```
typedef struct{
     char label[20];
     unsigned int id;
     t_node contents[50];
 } folder;
```

Now, i obviously want label to contain the raw byte string with in it the name (even better would be the raw string without trailing 0, but that's a sacrifice I am willing to make).

No,here's how I create and use a struct:

```
folder* myFolder = (folder *) malloc(sizeof(folder));
myFolder->label = "name";

//Which doesn't work, if I try this:

char name[20] = "name";
myFolder->label = name;

//this too, doesn't work.
```

The error message says "incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[20]’ from type ‘char *’".
Which I understand, but don't know how to resolve.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Use `strncpy()`:

```
char name[20] = "name";
strncpy(myFolder->label, name, sizeof(myFolder->label) - 1);
myFolder->label[sizeof(myFolder->label) - 1] = 0;
```

Comment: I don't agree; `strncpy` is not safer than `strcpy`. It was introduced to deal with fixed-length name fields in structures, not to provide a "bounded" `strcpy`.

Comment: @Kirilenko: Well, we *are* dealing with a fixed-length struct field, aren't we?

Comment: "strncpy was initially introduced into the C library to deal with fixed-length name fields in structures such as directory entries.  Such fields are not used in the same way as strings: the trailing null is unnecessary for a maximum-length field, and setting trailing bytes for shorter names to null assures efficient field-wise comparisons.  strncpy is not by origin a ``bounded strcpy,'' and the Committee has preferred to recognize existing practice rather than alter the function to better suit it to such use."

Answer (score 2):

Try using `strncpy()`:

```
strncpy( myFolder->label, "name", 20 );
```

instead of

```
myFolder->label = "name";
```

You cannot use the assignment operator to fill the array, in this case the right hand side of "name" will resolve to a char pointer.

Also I would suggest replacing the constant 20 with some defined constant indicating what the value is (ie MAX_FOLDER_LABEL_LEN).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [strcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)

```
strcpy(myFolder->label, "name");
```

Answer (score 1):

An array is not a modifiable lvalue, so you can't assign a value to it. You have several solutions:

- declares `label` as pointer to `char`;
- use `strcpy` (or equivalent).

Comment: now that wouldn't be very practical (your first option), because the node is part of a filesystem (will be written to disk). To locate the label anywhere else in the fs just because malloc pointed there would make it quite sluggish. The suggestion was welcome though.