# Getting a segmentation fault in my code

Tags: c

My code is giving me a segmentation fault. I'm 99% sure the fault is stemming from my lousy code construction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

int decToBit(unsigned int I, char *str){

        str = "";
        int currentVal = I;

        do{
                if(I%2 == 0)
                        strcat(str,"0");
                else
                        strcat(str,"1");

                 } while(currentVal > 0);

        return(0);
}
```

Comment: By doing `str = "";`, `decToBit()` ignores the original value of `str`.  Likely want `str[0] = '\0'`;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273623/c-structure-member-is-a-string-how-to-assign-bytes-directly/13273656#13273656

Comment: @chux Wow awesome suggestion, you're a life saver. My code finally ran

Comment: @user2460844 Many folk contributed.  Consider up-voting all useful answers once you reach 15+ rep points.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that there is enough space in `str` to add the extra characters:

```
char myStr[200];
myStr[0] = '\0';  // make sure you start with a "zero length" string.
strcpy(myStr, str);
```

and then use `myStr` where you were using `str`.

As it is, the statement

```
str="";
```

points `str` to a `const char*` - that is a string you can read but not write.

Incidentally the call signature for main is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

in other words, you need a pointer to a pointer to char. If I am not mistaken, you would like to do the following (a bit of mind reading here):

Every odd argument gets a 1 added; every even argument gets a 0 added.

If my mind reading trick worked, then you might want to try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  char temp[200];
  temp[0] = '\0';
  int ii;

  for(ii = 0; ii < argc; ii++) {
    strncpy(temp, argv[ii], 200); // safe copy
    if(ii%2==0) {
      strcat(temp, "0");
    }
    else {
      strcat(temp, "1");
    }
    printf("%s\n", temp);
  }
}
```

**edit** just realized you edited the question and now your purpose is much clearer.

Modified your function a bit:

```
int decToBit(unsigned int I, char *str){

  str[0] = '\0';
  char *digit;
  do
  {
    digit = "1";
    if ( I%2  == 0) digit = "0";
    strcat(str, digit);
    I>>=1;
  } while (I != 0);

  return(0);
}
```

It seems to work...

Comment: My apologies for not making this clear, but this method is receiving a str and its size from a main class

Comment: "A main class"? You tagged this as `C`. And you have a `main` function… well see if my updated answer is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

In do-while loop you should increment  the value of currentVal. Otherwise it will be an infinity loop and you will end up with Segmentation fault.

Comment: An infinite loop is a problem, but by itself shouldn't cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Xymostech - it will eventually if you keep appending to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `str[0]` properly.
Divide I by 2 each loop.

But then the string will be in a little endian order.  Doubt that was intended?

```
int decToBit(unsigned int I, char *str) {
  str[0] = '\0';
  do {
    if (I%2 == 0)
      strcat(str,"0");
    else
      strcat(str,"1");
    I /= 2;
  } while(I > 0);
  return(0);
}

// call example
char buf[sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT + 1];
decToBit(1234567u, buf);
```

Comment: @Floris Yes, but it appears OP is doing a little bit endian order.  Maybe that will be the next post?

Comment: Since OP can't upvote your answer yet, I will. And maybe (s)he will figure out how to accept an answer before long?...

Comment: @Floris In the mean time I can get hypnotized by the [HAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_9000) eye of yours.

Comment: yours is a far more hypnotic avatar!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>

char *decToBit(unsigned int I, char *str){
    int bit_size = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(I);
    str += bit_size;
    *str = 0;
    do{
        *--str = "01"[I & 1];
    }while(I>>=1);
    return str;
}

int main(){
    char bits[33];
    printf("%s\n", decToBit(0, bits));
    printf("%s\n", decToBit(-1, bits));
    printf("%s\n", decToBit(5, bits));
    return 0;
}
```